# L2-norm with estimated weights

Tags: normed-spaces, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent, regression-analysis

Suppose I'm performing linear regression. My lecturer said the formula below can be used for estimating the weight vector that is passed to the L2-norm part of the loss function but he didn't elaborate. I have 2 questions. When is it a good idea to do so and why? And if I am to do the gradient descent manually do I have to update these weights in addition to the "normal" ones?

$$w = (X^TX + λI_p)^{-1}X^Ty$$

X - design matrix;

y - vector from training data (x,y)

$I_p$ - identity matrix where p is the dimension of the weight vector

λ - regularization coefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the Ridge regression. The original motivation for using Ridge regression was to deal with complete and high colinearity between the explained variables. The larger the $\lambda$ the more stable model you will have and less information will be used from the design matrix $X^TX$.  Another effect of the so-called $l_2$ regularization is shrinkage of the weights $w$. The largest the $\lambda$ the smaller the weights. This introduces bias, but reduces variance (as part of the bias-variance trade-off). Regarding the second question - there is a close form solution, $(X'X - \lambda I )^{-1} X'y$, no need in gradient descent.

Comment: Would it ever be a good idea to use 2 sets of weights - one randomly initialized for the actual model and we try to modify these weights to arrive at the optimal weights and another set of weights for the regularization that we obtain from the closed form? And if I am to do that, do I have to update the the second set of weights too? Keep in mind I am using a custom loss function when asking these questions.

Comment: It sounds somehow unconventional. The closed form solution minimizes the square loss function subject to the constrained given a constant $\lambda$. Given that, you can obtain the optimal lambda by minimizing the total variance, i.e., $\hat{\sigma}^2tr(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}$. You can use other methods to obtain the weights. like LASSO or the regular least square and then choose the best model by minimization of the prediction error.